# How to use the ReadWriter for parameterized types

Tags: scala, upickle

I am trying to migrate to the latest version of upickle 0.7.1. Where I had previously passed around implicit Readers and Writers I believe I must now use a single ReadWriter and explicitly define them in a companion object for any case classes I want to serialize. But I cannot figure out how this works for a parameterized type. So for example say I had the following before upgrading (from 0.4.4):

```
trait OldTrait[T] {

    implicit val evr: Reader[T]
    implicit val evw: Writer[T]

    def save(t: T): String = write(t)
    def restore(str: String): T = read[T](str)
}

class MyOldClass[T](implicit val evr: Reader[T], val evw: Writer[T]) extends OldTrait[T] {
}

case class Request[T](msg: T)

val c1 = new MyOldClass[Request[Int]]
```

The above code compiled fine for me. To migrate this code I have tried the following:

```
trait NewTrait[T] {
    implicit val evrw: ReadWriter[T]
}

class MyNewClass[T](implicit val evrw: ReadWriter[T]) extends NewTrait[T] {

}

object Request {
    implicit val rw: ReadWriter[Request[_]] = macroRW
}

val c2 = new MyNewClass[Request[Int]]
```

But this will not compile for me. I get the following errors:

> Don't know how to derive type ...Request[*]       implicit val rw:
>   ReadWriter[Request[*]] = macroRW
>
> ... could not find implicit value for parameter evrw:
>   upickle.default.ReadWriter[Request[Int]]
>
> ...not enough arguments for constructor MyNewClass: (implicit evrw:
>   upickle.default.ReadWriter[Request[Int]])MyNewClass[Request[Int]].
>   Unspecified value parameter evrw.     val c2 = new
>   MyNewClass[Request[Int]]

What would be the correct approach to migrating the old code?

Comment: are you sure it worked with upickle 0.4.4? It does not compile for me, giving an error: `could not find implicit value for parameter evr: upickle.default.Reader[ammonite.$sess.cmd5.Request[Int]]
val c1 = new MyOldClass[Request[Int]]
         ^
Compilation Failed`

Comment: Yes tested again and compiles fine in 0.4.4. But if I use version 0.7.1 I get that same error. Maybe you compiled with a later version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested, but I would expect you need

```
implicit def rw[T: ReadWriter]: ReadWriter[Request[T]] = macroRW
```

So e.g. because there is a `ReadWriter[Int]`, there's also a `ReadWriter[Request[Int]]`.

(I would be very surprised if this doesn't work, but you can certainly do it manually instead of `macroRW` in this case.)